# Why is my web.config being overwritten when I publish?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC website project.

`web.config` set the property `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Do not copy`.

Yet when I publish the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is changed from `Production` to `Development` - why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Copy to output directory is for copying to bin folder, not for publish. and on local machine ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  will always be Development. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is an environment variable, and it's set by your publish profile.

[Environment variables in Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

See: For Windows IIS deployments: Include the  property in the publish profile (.pubxml) or project file. This approach sets the environment in web.config when the project is published